# admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter doesnt work with multi-level relations

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filter

I am working on Django admin. I have the 3 models

```
class University(models.Model)
    ...

class Institution(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey(University)

class Course(models.Model):
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution)
```

In admin, I want list filtred to have filter by University but only shows universities that have institutions with added courses. I use

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('institution__university',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),
        ...
    )
```

I am getting the error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'university' into the field. Choices are ...
```

How can I achieve that? help please

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the Choices?

Comment: choices are Institution fields : name, president, added_on, ...

Comment: Are you sure, that you apply the admin to the correct model?

Comment: sorry for Model1Admin (error was just in the question code not in my files code).

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an error because the items you are listing have no relation to the field: `university`, they have a relationship to `institution`.

if  you change:

```
('institution__university',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter)
```

to:

```
('institution',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter)
```

or possibly:

```
('university',admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter)
```

it should get rid of the error.  It will not, however, likely do specifically what you are wanting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Django 1.10, see here https://github.com/django/django/commit/815f4d206dfea41bdff167283c2cac43a71524ac